# Do all solidity functions in an imported interface get compiled into the smart contract bytecode, even if they aren't used?

Tags: interface, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to keep a contract as small as possible. I know that if you import a solidity library, only the functions actually utilized in that library get compiled into the contract, increasing it's size.

I'm not sure if that goes for importing interfaces.

For example:

```
interface IDoThings {
    function transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) external;
    function setValue(uint256 newVal) external;
    function owner() external view returns (address);
}

contract DoingThings {
    function getOwnerOfAnotherContract(address target) public view returns (address) {
        return IDoThings(target).owner();
    }
}
```

When this get's compiled down, will the function selectors for `transfer` & `setValue` also be included in the contract's bytecode, or will only the `owner` function selector be included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interface` is like `typescript` types, they are used in compilation time and in the javascript bundle you do not see any `type` definitions.

If you compile your code at `https://remix.ethereum.org/`

[image]

this is what you will get

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "target",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getOwnerOfAnotherContract",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

there is nothing about interface or its function signatures

Comment: whoops, shoulda just done that haha. makes total sense to just go to the actual bytecode/abi. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They do not.

Solidity v0.8 without bytecode optimizer:

- with the unused interface declarations: 554 bytes
- without: 554 bytes